# ASP.NET DataGrid ClientID value returning null

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datagrid, clientid

I see that there were lot of questions on getting ClientID in ASP.NET but all the questions that I've looked did not help for my scenario. I'm a bit new to ASP.NET and have issues in getting the ClientID of a DataGrid in JavaScript.

Hope someone in this forum help me to find a way.

On my aspx page, I got a datagrid:

```
 <div class="tblgrid" id="divItems">
    <asp:DataGrid ID="dgItems" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None">
    <Columns>
         <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="EmpId" DataField="EmpId">
         </asp:BoundColumn>
         <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="F_Name" DataField="F_Name">
         </asp:BoundColumn>
         <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="L_Name" DataField="L_Name">
         </asp:BoundColumn>
         <asp:BoundColumn DataField="City" HeaderText="City">
         </asp:BoundColumn>
         .....
    </Columns>
```

When I'm using the following in my JavaScript, it is returning appropriate table inner HTML in the alert message.

```
  alert(document.getElementById('ct100_PageContent_dgItems').innerHTML);
```

but when I'm using the ASP.NET ClientID, I'm getting a null value exception because it is throwing a  null value.

```
  alert(document.getElementById('<%=dgItems.ClientID %>').innerHTML);
```

Can anyone help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see what actually render on page on this point `<%=dgItems.ClientID %>`. Maybe you call it early and the id is not yet made...

Comment: _ct100_PageContent_dgItems_ is the id that I'm getting on the page source in the browser, I'm using both chrome browser console and javascript file to see whether it is returning anything. but null was the only value that it is providing at this moment.

Comment: something you do wrong here and with that code we can not find it. If you maybe have it online we can see it, but you need to debug it and find your bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `document.getElementById('<%=dgItems.ClientID %>')` 
is in a separate JS file to that of the aspx page, then the ASP.Net engine will not be able to resolve the reference. It only works for scripts embedded within the .aspx page.

A solution however is if you aren't duplicating the DataGrid on the page then you could give it a static id using `ClientIDMode="static"`:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgItems" ClientIDMode="static" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None">
```

and then reference it with

```
document.getElementById('dgItems')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`alert(document.getElementById('<%=dgItems.ClientID %>').innerHTML);`

.. you could give the DataGrid a CSS class, for example 'dgrid' and use a jQuery class selector to find it client side ?